# Adding a line to a ggplot2 plot and tweaking legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to show points colored by value. In addition, I want to show a regression line on this data.

This is an example of the data that I am using:

```
structure(list(a = c(63.635707116462, 59.7200565823145, 56.0311239027684, 
53.1573088984712, 51.0192317467653, 48.0727441921859, 47.1516684444444, 
45.5081981068289, 43.5874967485549, 43.3163255512322), b = c(278.983796321269, 
254.833332215134, 234.812503036992, 221.519477352253, 212.013474843663, 
199.926648466351, 194.577007436116, 186.506133515809, 179.411968705754, 
172.056487287103), col = c(18.36245, 22.03494, 25.70743, 29.37992, 
33.05241, 36.7249, 40.39739, 44.06988, 47.74237, 51.41486), predict = c(275.438415187452, 
256.049214397717, 237.782656695549, 223.552332598712, 212.965175538386, 
198.374997400175, 193.814089203754, 185.676086057123, 176.165312823424, 
174.82254927815)), .Names = c("a", "b", "col", "predict"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code I am using so far is as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b, colour=col)) + geom_point()
p + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

However, this does  not produce a straight line (as it is smoothed) so instead I tried to follow one of the examples on [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_smooth.html) (which is using `qplot`) and did the following:

```
model <- lm(b ~ a, data = df)
df$predict <- stats::predict(model, newdata=df) 
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b, colour=col) ) + geom_point() 
p + geom_line(aes(x = a, y = predict))
```

In the example, a line is added using `+ geom_line(data=grid)`, which in my case would be `+ geom_line(data=df)`. This just joins the points together, instead of drawing a straight line on the plot. How can I plot a line on this plot that is perfectly straight?

The other problem I was having with the plot, is renaming the legend. I want to have a two word title for the data (e.g. 'Z Density'), but I don't know how to change it. I've tried using `+ scale_colour_discrete(name = "Fancy Title")` and `+ scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Fancy Title")` using advice from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/how-can-i-change-the-title-of-a-legend-in-ggplot2) question but they do not work as my data is colored by a value.

Comment: I believe that `geom_smooth(stat=lm, ...) will in fact produce a perfectly straight line, as you desire.

Comment: for `qplot()` using `geom_smooth(method = "lm")` does work (though the line is not perfectly straight), but `geom_smooth(stat=lm, ...)` (or `"lm"`) does not appear to work for `ggplot`

Comment: Straight lines often look jagged on the screen due to it being comprised of pixel rather than a continuous medium. Traditionally, anti-aliasing is used to combat this, which I think the default device on the Mac uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Andrie says, using method = "lm" gives a linear model. As for your second question, use `scale_color_continuous()`

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b, colour=col)) + geom_point()
p + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
    scale_colour_continuous(name = "My Legend")
```

You also don't need to do all of the predicting. `ggplot()` will do this for you, which is one of the great benefits.

Comment: You can also label the legend simply by using `labs(colour = "Fancy Title")`.